# Is there a way to calculate the coefficient determination if the values of x and y are not given?

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation, r-squared, scatterplot

so I am having a problem to calculate the r-squared because the values of the variable (y and x) are not given in the question. All I have is the mean and the standard deviation of each variable as well as the scatter plot with pearson correlation value.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#As_squared_correlation_coefficient):

> In linear least squares regression with an estimated intercept term,
>   $R^2$ equals the square of the Pearson correlation coefficient between
>   the observed $y$ and modeled (predicted) $f$ data values of the
>   dependent variable. In a univariate linear least squares regression,
>   this is also equal to the squared Pearson correlation coefficient of
>   the dependent $y$ explanatory $x$ variables.

So square your Pearson correlation to get the $R^2$ value if you have simple linear regression, which I assume you do.

Comment: I am not sure if that what I am supposed to do because the questions has 4 marks so squaring the correlation won't do !